# Track document opening history in shaepoint

Tags: sharepoint, moss

We have some documents in controlled library section of our sharepoint site. Is it possible to keep a track of the history of persons who have opened or read the file/document?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use [SharePoint's auditing functionality](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA010100005.aspx). As you are using MOSS (rather than WSS) a User Interface to control this is included.

For future SharePoint related questions you may want to consider [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)